# How to do a spinning animation while downloading a file

Tags: android

I have a program that copies a file to the sd card.  The program takes a while to run, and now it just freezes while the file is being copied.

I saw some other programs that have a animation of a wheel spinning in the center of the screen while the file is being down loaed.

I tried to google spin control, but this brought up animation about a selector control using spinning wheels.

Is this feature built into the android?

Comment: are you interested to have something like this http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ProgressBar widget with indeterminate="true".  You can use a ProgressDialog, read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Also, learn about threads, as you should be doing your file save in a background thread.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to download the file. This will prevent your UI from freezing, and also easily allows you to show progress information if you want. If you want to let it download in the background, and let the user continue using the app, that's doable as well.

You can find an AsyncTask in one of my open source projects that downloads a file and shows the progress information using a progress bar [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker/blob/master/UpdateChecker/src/com/appaholics/updatechecker/DownloadManager.java). You can change the style of the progress dialog to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using some sort of AsyncTask to download it?

If this is the case you can make an indeterminate progress bar start spinning right before you call task.execute() and then in onPostExecute() you can set the progress bar's visibility to view.GONE

here is an example on progress bars: http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-progressbar-example/